# Tuning for Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I need to increase performance of this query:

```
 select t.*
        ,(select max(1)
          from schema1.table_a t1
          where  1=1
                    to_date(t.misdate, 'YYYYMMDD') between t1.startdateref and t1.enddateref
                     and sysdate between t1.startdatevalue and t1.enddatevalue
                     and t1.idpma = t.idpm)
     from schema2.table_b t
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar`? That is a really bad idea

Comment: I know, but we can't choose it.

Comment: 1=1 will create a cartesian join and thus reduce performance.  Take a look at refactoring the SQL.  I would try to become familiar with `explain plan for <sql query>` and then running a `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)`

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have any filtering condition on `table_b`. This means the best plan includes a **full table scan** on table_b. This would be optimal.

Having said that, now you need to focus on `table_a`. That one should be accessed using **index range scans** on either:

- `idpma`, then by `startdateref`.
- or `idpma`, then by `startdateref`.

Yes, it's one or the other. For Oracle's cost-based optimizer (CBO) to pick the best plan, you'll need to add the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on schema1.table_a (idpma, startdateref);

create index ix2 on schema1.table_a (idpma, startdatevalue);
```

Try with this ones and see how it works.